# For array of ActiveRecord objects, return array of their attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

```
@matched = [1, 2, 3]
```

Where each integer represents the id of an ActiveRecord object in the `Inventory` class. As a next step, I want to look at each of those objects and obtain the email of the parent `User`, but I'm not sure how to do it. Ideally I'd write something like:

```
Inventory.where(id: @matched).user.email
```

Because certainly, this statement would work if I only had a single `id` to look up. Since that doesn't work, I'm instead doing this

```
@email = []
@matched.each do |i|
   @email << Inventory.find_by_id(i).user.email
end
```

Just wondering if there's an easier way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the email addresses then you can use the `pluck` method:

```
Inventory.where(id: @matched).joins(:user).pluck("users.email")
```

Comment: This is way better than my answer. I'm such a hacker I swear

Comment: I was going to post an answer with `Array#map` but this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Inventory

  def self.with_ids(ids) 
    sql = @matched.map{|id| "id = #{id}"}.join(" OR ")
    where(sql)
  end

  def parent_email
    user.email
  end
 end

Inventory.with_ids(@matched).map(&:parent_email)
```